# C# Initialize a Dictionary locally and once (static equivalent in C++)

Tags: c#, dictionary, initialization, local

I have a function that instantiates and populates a Dictionary. I use the function to convert a Byte key (its parameter) into an enum value (its returned value).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the first byte of the received data from USB into a Model B event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Model_B_Event Get_Event_From_Data(Byte[] data)
    {
        Dictionary<Byte, Model_B_Event> map = new Dictionary<byte, Model_B_Event>();
        Model_B_Event matching_event = Model_B_Event.NO_EVENT;

        map.Add(0, Model_B_Event.SEND_MODEL_ID);
        map.Add(5, Model_B_Event.SEND_RELAY_VOLTAGE);
        map.Add(6, Model_B_Event.SEND_SPARE_STATUS);

        map.TryGetValue(data[0], out matching_event);

        return matching_event;
    }
```

I was thinking in C++ terms and I wanted to add the static property to

```
static Dictionary<Byte, Model_B_Event> map = new Dictionary<byte, Model_B_Event>();
```

so that the dictionary is only built once every time the function is run. I would only check with a Boolean flag if I already built the dictionary before.

However, the static property is not available in C# for local variables.

Is there a way to build this dictionary only once and a way to have it only locally in the function? I don't want to share it to the class.

Thanks.

Comment: In C#, state between calls is done through instance fields.

Comment: `However, the static property is not available in C#.`  What?  `static` exists in both languages and means the same thing in each.

Comment: Make it a field and you can mark it static.

Comment: @Servy The static property is not available in C# in local variables. I am editing the post.

Comment: @SantiagoVillafuerte Then you have your answer.  C# doesn't have static locals.  If you want it to be static, it will need to be not local.

Comment: @Servy I was looking for an equivalence. Thanks. I read somewhere else that Visual Basic does have an equivalence to static (local scope).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way of declaring a static variable in C# other than as a class variable. However, by declaring your field as private, there is no risk that it will get accidentally consumed externally; it can only be accessed from within the class itself.

You can declare it as a static lazily-initialized field:

```
private static readonly Lazy<Dictionary<byte, Model_B_Event>> map =
    new Lazy<Dictionary<byte, Model_B_Event>>(() =>
        new Dictionary<byte, Model_B_Event>
        {
            { 0, Model_B_Event.SEND_MODEL_ID },
            { 5, Model_B_Event.SEND_RELAY_VOLTAGE },
            { 6, Model_B_Event.SEND_SPARE_STATUS },
        });

/// <summary>
/// Convert the first byte of the received data from USB into a Model B event
/// </summary>
/// <param name="data"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
Model_B_Event Get_Event_From_Data(Byte[] data)
{
    if (map.Value.TryGetValue(data[0], out matching_event))
        return matching_event;

    return Model_B_Event.NO_EVENT;
}
```

Comment: `Lazy<T>` causes an object to be initialized only upon first request. It's similar to the boolean flag you suggested, but provides more functionality, such as thread-safety.